# Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: stripe.redirectToCheckout: You must provide one of lineItems, items, or sessionId

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I think the problem is in `sessionId:sesId`.can't seem to get session's id, also I'm new to Stripe

here's **serverfund.php**

```
<?php

require './../vendor/autoload.php';

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 if(!empty($_POST['charity']) && !empty($_POST['currency'])  && !empty($_POST['donation']))
 {
    $paymentMethodType = [
        'TND' => ['card'],
        'AED' > ['card'],
        'eur' => ['car', 'giropay', 'ideal'],
        'USD' => ['card'],
    ];
    $post = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

     $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('pk_test_51K6iWrIHK9zkttmZWkOHEfGax38CO8hFR4qWtxiVj8nIy8xcITk3tPfLrxxl5YfD89X7eL3yl2XumzX064Ll6mis00RdLdmsIm');
     $session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
        'success_url' => 'http://localhost:8080/frontend/fund.html?status=success',
        'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost:8080/frontend/fund.html?status=failure',
        'mode' => 'payment',
        'submit_type' => 'donate',
        'payment_method_types'  => $paymentMethodType[$post['currency']],
        'line_items' => [
            [
                'quantity' => 1,
                'price_data' =>[
                    'currency' => $post['currency'],
                    'unit_amount' => $post['donation'],
                    'product_data' => [
                        'name' => $post['charity']
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]

     ]);

    echo $session->id;
 }


}


 ?>
```

and **fund.js**

```
const donate4 = document.querySelector('#charity')
const currency = document.querySelector('#currency')
const donation = document.querySelector('#donation')
const donationbtn = document.querySelector('button')


if(donationbtn){
donationbtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_51K6iWrIHK9zkttmZWkOHEfGax38CO8hFR4qWtxiVj8nIy8xcITk3tPfLrxxl5YfD89X7eL3yl2XumzX064Ll6mis00RdLdmsIm');
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/backend/serverfund.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: new FormData(document.querySelector('.form-donation'))
        })
        
        .then(res => res.text())
        .then(sesId => {
            
            stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId:sesId})

        })

})
}
```

Comment: Are you actually returning the `session_id` from `serverfund.php` or just echoing it?

Comment: I was following a tutorial, she did it like that and it worked for her

Comment: Try adding `console.log(sesId);` before the call to `redirectToCheckout` to make sure you actually have the id there

Comment: i tried `console.log(sesId);`  it's empty

Comment: Ok try this. Change your first `then` call to:
`.then(response => response.text())`

Comment: I've changed `.then(res => res.text())` to `.then(response => response.text())` but I still got the same error

Comment: Then the server must not be retuning the id. I'm not too familiar with the php side of it, but that's where I would start looking. Hopefully this was helpful at least. Good luck!